# Which of the two "schaffen" verbs is this?

Tags: verb

> Du kannst dreimal so viele Kunden **schaffen** wie bislang.

I don't know how to put this, but I understand that there exist two different "schaffen" verbs with identical spelling, one using the past participle "geschaffen" while the other using "geschafft".

I wonder which of the two "schaffen"s this is?

> ... ***create***/***make*** three times as many customers ... [the one with "geschaffen"]
>
> or: ... ***manage*** three times as many customers ... [the one with "geschafft"]

Answer (score 1):

You do not create customers. Customers are people who are born, not created.

But you work with customers, you handle them, you have to deal with them, i.e. you *manage* them.

So when you say

> Du kannst dreimal so viele Kunden schaffen wie bislang.

then it is the same *schaffen* like in Merkels famous quote about refugees from 2015:

> Wir schaffen das.

When you put both sentences into past tense, you get:

> Du hast dreimal so viele Kunden **geschafft** wie davor.
>   Wir haben das **geschafft.**

Comment: You could add the common German verb for *to create* is **erschaffen**, and *schaffen* is seldom used in the meaning of *to create*.

Comment: One could imagine that customers are created by turning non-customers into customers. But this is not the meaning of *schaffen* here.

Comment: @RHa: Maybe this might work in English, but not in German. »*Schaffen*« in the sense of »*erschaffen*« is not adding a property to something that already exists. »*Schaffen*« is to bring something into existence that didn't exist before.